# error launch test electron: browserType.launch: Executable doesn't exist

Tags: node.js, electron, playwright

Playwright Version: [v 1.39.0] Operating System: [Windows 11.] Desktop: [Electron] Node.js: 18.17.1
I am running a test to test the electron application. An error occurs, the autotest on playwright is trying to launch the chrome browser. How to make the browser not start. And only the electron application was launched?

The test is initialized in a separate file support.js

```
let electronApp =  await electron.launch({ executablePath });
```

Then the initialization result is assigned to the context variable in the main test file, and passed as a function parameter to new functions in support.js

```
async loginSpetialist(UserName, context)
```

I'm trying to run a test. I expect it to run without chrome, so that it can run tests on the web and desktop separately.